# Multiple values in query range value in Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

How to build query with multiple values. I need to create filter which display only active BOMs in grid and I looking for solution. Here is my code which isnt working:

```
public void executeQuery() 
{
QueryBuildRange         qbr;
QueryRun                queryRun;
Query q = new Query();

qbr = SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(BOMTable_q.dataSourceTable(tableNum(BOMTable)), fieldNum(BOMTable, BOMId));

if (activeButton==false)
{
    qbr.value(SysQuery::valueUnlimited());
}   
else
{
    while select BOMVersion where BOMVersion.Active==true && BOMVersion.Approved==true{
    qbr.value(queryValue(BOMVersion.BOMId));
}
super();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

1. add multiple ranges
2. add multiple values to one range separated by commna

### Option 1:

```cs
QueryBuildDataSource qbds = q.dataSourceTable(BOMTable);
QueryBuildRange qbr;
while (...)
{
    qbr = qbds.addRange(fieldNum(BOMTable, BOMId));
    qbr.value(queryValue(BOMVersion.BOMId));
}
```

### Option 2:

```cs
QueryBuildRange qbr = q.dataSourceTable(BOMTable).addRange(fieldNum(BOMTable, BOMId));
container c;
while (...)
{
    c+= queryValue(BOMVersion.BOMId);
}
qbr.value(con2str(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

use like below

```
query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(BOMTable)).addRange(Fieldnum(BOMTable, Approved)).value(strFmt('((%1.%3 == 0) || (%2.%4 == 0))',
                    query.dataSourceTable(tablenum(BOMTable)).name(),
                    query.dataSourceTable(tablenum(BOMVersion)).name(),
                    fieldStr(BOMTable,Approved),
                    fieldStr(BOMVersion,Approved)));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).